# Python MemoryError with metric-learn

Tags: python, numpy, out-of-memory, nearest-neighbor

I am trying to learn a new distance metric using neighborhood component analysis ([using this source](https://all-umass.github.io/metric-learn/metric_learn.nca.html))

My data matrix has the shape of 11000x128 (11k elements and 128 features). However I keep getting memory error, I even downsized my input data to 1000x128 but I still get the Memory error. Here is my code snippet. I am using a C4.8xlarge machine on AWS (36 cores, 60 GiB Memory). Is there a way that I can bypass this? How do I make sure that I am using all the available cores?

```
from metric_learn import NCA    
num_el = 1000
nca = NCA(max_iter=1, learning_rate=0.01)
nca.fit(feats_annotated[:num_el], labels_annotated[:num_el])
```

---

```
       MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-5-bfd6fe47f16d> in <module>()
          1 num_el = 1000
          2 nca = NCA(max_iter=1, learning_rate=0.01)
    ----> 3 nca.fit(feats_annotated[:num_el], labels_annotated[:num_el])

    /home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/metric_learn/nca.pyc in fit(self, X, labels)
         34     # Run NCA
         35     dX = X[:,None] - X[None]  # shape (n, n, d)
    ---> 36     tmp = np.einsum('...i,...j->...ij', dX, dX)  # shape (n, n, d, d)
         37     masks = labels[:,None] == labels[None]
         38     learning_rate = self.params['learning_rate']

    /home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/einsumfunc.pyc in einsum(*operands, **kwargs)
        946     # If no optimization, run pure einsum
        947     if optimize_arg is False:
    --> 948         return c_einsum(*operands, **kwargs)
        949 
        950     valid_einsum_kwargs = ['out', 'dtype', 'order', 'casting']

    MemoryError:
```

Comment: This is my memory status: **svmem(total=63320264704, available=54810333184, percent=13.4, used=8389054464, free=32625438720, active=20517072896, inactive=8142704640, buffers=638541824, cached=21667229696, shared=155648)** so I should have 50GB free

Comment: I added the `numpy` tag because the error occurs in a `np.einsum`.  When asking questions like this it helps if you identify, in tags, the special packages that you are using.  It's doing a matrix product (dot product) that's too large for memory.  If `n` is `num_el` and `d` is `128`, it's try to make an array with 1000*1000*128*128 elements.